# Make Ember router transition to route from a click event

Tags: ember.js, router

I got a Leaflet map rendered as a view with controller in *application template* like `{{view "map" locations }}`. *locations* is an array of location models.

In *index route* the *locations* data is loaded and set on *application controller* to be passed on to the map view. This happens that way because other routes can set another content for *locations* and so change the markers on the map.

In the *map* view the Leaflet map is set up and the markers are created from *locations*. I want to be each marker to be clickable, so the app transitions to the route where the “clicked” location is described in detail. Therefor I have to bind a click event handler right after creation when I have the location model at hand like

```
mapMarker.on('click', function(ev) {
  // Do transition to 'location' with model location
});
```

I’d love to keep the routing stuff in the *router*/*routes*. In a template I’d use a *link-to* helper, but how to a transition from a click event defined within a view? I tried to use *sendAction* but it seems this doesn’t work here because of the view being rendered in its on scope so the action doesn’t bubble up to *application route*. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the click event to bubble up to the routes you have to send it to the current controller.

```
this.get('controller').send('someEvent')
```

Doing just `send()` makes the action bubble up only to parent views.

Now, if you were to use the `action` helper in your template, in that case it goes directly to the controller. And if the controller doesn't implement the action, it will bubble up to the route.

See http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling

Comment: Thanks, it works! Still have to wrap my head around the action stuff in Ember.